# How to see Qt5 QString contents while debugging on Visual Studio 2015

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2015, qt5, natvis

I'm using visual studio 2015 and Qt5.

I'have already added qt5.natvis on Vislaualizers folders.
I have set the "Use Native Compatibility Mode" option in Tools > Options > Debugging > General menu.

Even so, QString value does not appear correctly when debugging. Only memory direction appears on Locals/Autos/Watch windows. Any idea?

I have set Verbose option for Native diagnostic messages and this is what I get:

```
Natvis: Parsing natvis xml file: D:\<user_name>\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Visualizers\qt5.natvis.
Natvis: Fatal error: 
Natvis: Parsing natvis xml file: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\PYTHON TOOLS FOR VISUAL STUDIO\2.2\PythonDkm.natvis.
Natvis: Fatal error: 
Natvis: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers\qt.natvis(128,25): Error: a pointer to a bound function may only be used to call the function
Error while evaluating 'd->data,sub' in the context of type '<executable>!QString'.
Natvis: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers\qt.natvis(127,6): Ignoring visualizer for type 'QString' labeled as 'QString' because one or more sub-expressions was invalid.
```

Comment: hi and welcome to StackOverflow!

please [edit] your question to clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.

what does "unable to see QString values" mean?

 see the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1):

Original `qt5.natvis` from qt plugin for MSVS contains some strange problem. I use [alternative natvis](https://github.com/aleksey-nikolaev/natvis-collection).
I'm not sure if this will work correctly on MSVS 2015, if so, you can ask the author to help you

Answer (score 0):

You need to use older natvis files. The ones you're using appear to use functionality that wasn't available in VS 2015.

The natvis file comes from the `qt-labs/vstools` repository. GitHub's online browser shows [two revisions for `src/qtvstools/qt5.natvis.xml`](https://github.com/qt-labs/vstools/commits/dev/src/qtvstools/qt5.natvis.xml), one from 2018, another from 2020.

The the 2018 revision also renamed the file from [`src/qtvisualizer/qt5.natvis.xml`, with one prior revision](https://github.com/qt-labs/vstools/commits/d665f3f5d3ce9df1cc88d162e7c85b3d136174db/src/qtvisualizer/qt5.natvis).

Since the oldest revision is from 2016, maybe that'd work for you with VS 2015.